# Titanium - emailDialog not supported on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am trying to use the emailDialog provided by the Titanium api's. But, it shows an unsupported action or 'No apps can perform this function : Send'.

Then on checking, my device returns False for isSupported call.

```
var emailDialog = Titanium.UI.createEmailDialog();
    alert(emailDialog.isSupported());
    emailDialog.setSubject('Hello from Titanium!');
    emailDialog.setToRecipients(['saurav.xxxxxx@live.com']);
    emailDialog.setCcRecipients(['saurav.xxxxxx@outlook.com']);
    emailDialog.setMessageBody('Appcelerator Titanium Rocks!');

    emailDialog.open();
```

My target API level is 18 and i am testing it on an android emulator.

Any help in resolving the issue will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Saurav

Comment: Have u some email app installed?

Comment: yes, i do have the default(pre-installed) email app on the emulator.

Comment: I do not want to send the email, i understand, installing on the device is a better option for that, its just wanted to see how the emailDialog screen appears from my App and the controls it provide.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Email app, and configure an account with it. Until you do that, you can not register and use EMAIL intents on the emulator.